# Destination Relationship Not Found in Survey123?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, arcgis-survey123

The goal of my project is to create a road sign inspection survey with the ability to take inspection photos.  I have some limitations, so I can only work with survey123 NOT collector.

I create the survey from a feature service. There are global IDs, everything is editable, attachments are enabled etc etc.

The trouble arises with the photo. Since I am doing the survey on existing geopoints (aka the signs), I can't just add a photo question.  The work around is add the photo question via a "repeat."  For this to work, I created a table and related it to the feature service layer then uploaded to AGOL. I really don't know what's going wrong or where to go from here. I'm having a hard time finding documentation on this topic, so I'm hoping someone can assist me.

I get this error message when I try to publish:
**The custom feature service submission url is not compatible with this survey (Destination relationship not found for table)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! Turns out I needed a **Relationship class** for this work.  A simple relate does not work.

Comment: Hi Katie, you can accept your own answer to close this topic, raise the tick sign

Comment: @aldo_tapia Looks like I have to wait 24 hours before I can accept my own answer.  But as soon as it's available, I will do so! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: and thanks for the answer, I'm a user of Survey123 and I didn't know that it could be possible to use relationship classes there